# R: how to extract data from a data.frame to plot a perspective plot?

Tags: r, plot

I am a beginner of R. I want to plot the numeral relations between different columns of a data frame.

Currently I have the following data frame:

```
    topN  Precision    Recall    F1Score udim idim tdim
10    50 0.02712121 0.2843955 0.04951998   67   78   50
40    50 0.02515152 0.2584113 0.04584124   67  156   50
70    50 0.02539924 0.2585877 0.04625516   67  234   50
100   50 0.02608365 0.2735997 0.04762680  133   78   50
130   50 0.02431818 0.2504262 0.04433146  133  156   50
160   50 0.02425856 0.2448997 0.04414439  133  234   50
190   50 0.02418251 0.2498824 0.04409746  200   78   50
220   50 0.02342205 0.2436125 0.04273533  200  156   50
250   50 0.02136882 0.2179636 0.03892181  200  234   50
```

**I want to plot the 3D relation between udim, idim and F1Score. I am using persp() function in R. I want to make sure if I am doing the right thing to use t() on z.**

So

x is udim: 67 133 200

y is idim: 78 156 234

z is their corresponding F1Score value in the data frame.

I use the following codes:

```
plot.data <- read.table(plot.file, sep=",", header=T) 
# plot.file is the data frame file location

udim <- as.factor(plot.data$udim)
u <-as.integer(levels(udim))

idim <- as.factor(plot.data$idim)
i <- as.integer(levels(idim))

t <- as.integer(levels(as.factor(plot.data$tdim)))

z <- outer(u, i, FUN = function(u, i){
  ss <- subset(plot.data, tdim == 50 & topN == 50) #udim == u & idim == i &
  ss$F1Score
})

persp(u, i, t(z), theta=45, phi=45, shade = 0.45, xlab="user dim", 
      ylab="item dim", zlab="F1 Score", scale=TRUE)
```

I got the following plot:

[image: 3D perspective plot: udim, idim, F1Score]

**Am I plotting it right? 
Is this the easiest/normal way to tackle with such task?**

**Actually in my data frame I have more rows with different values of topNs and tdim, so is it possible add one or two more dimensions, say tdim, topN, to reflect numeral relations between so many columns in a plot?**

Answer (score 1):

Your graph already looks nice and I cannot answer your second question.

However, I want to present you another option for 3-way graphs.
Although they are usually quite confusing, I found an appealing way to make use of 3D Scatterplots.
Using `scatterplot3d`and `animation` as well as some third party software like `ImageMagick (http://imagemagick.org)` you can create animated pictures of 3D Scatterplots, which are certainly an option for data presentation using a computer.

Sample for your data (I don't have the `animation` package installed right now so I can only give you the syntax for the plot):

```
 library(scatterplot3d)

 F1Score <- c(0.04951998,0.04584124,0.04625516,0.04762680,0.04433146,0.04414439,0.04409746,0.04273533,0.03892181)
 udim <- c(67,67,67,133,133,133,200,200,200)
 idim <- c(78,156,234,78,156,234,78,156,234)

 for (j in seq(5, 175, by = 5)) {
 scatterplot3d(udim, idim, F1Score, angle = j)
 Sys.sleep(0.042) # for 24 fps when looking at it in R
 }
```

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful. It seems like a better choice with angle changing:)

Comment: Usually avoid 3D Scatterplots but with the loop it is also a good tool for quick 3-way data examination when you have new data.